Grease staining behind backsplash tiles under range hood
We've lived in this house for about three years now and this problem has been gradually developing over that time. It seems as though the oil/grease that has precipitated in our range hood is able to migrate down behind the tiles of our backsplash, staining them in a really ugly way. I've been tracking the progress of this over the months and it does seem to get progressively worse, though I'm not sure what causes it.
I don't know how the range hood or tiles were originally installed. I assume it was a DIY job, based on the look of things.
We're planning on renovating the kitchen this summer, including installing a new backsplash. Before this, however, we'd like to know what is causing this so that we can make sure it doesn't happen in the future.
How can grease from the range hood get into the wall behind the backsplash, and what should we do during the renovation to prevent this?
Thank you!
Edit: I've added a picture of inside the range hood. There is a fold in the sheet metal in the corner, but otherwise it's a continuous surface and not obviously laden with grease. We do clean the filters routinely in the dishwasher, so they don't get too gunked up.
Something I was thinking about as a possible aggravating factor is that we make a lot of broth on the stove. The long cook time and all the steam may loosen the grease in the range hood and make it easier for it to migrate into the tile. Previous homeowners (who apparently had these tiles for years with no staining) may not have cooked the same way we do.
When we get new tiles, what should we look for to minimize the chances of this happening again?



How do you know grease is getting behind the tiles? Looks like a natural stone (which is slightly porous) and surface grease and staining to me. I think a glazed tile is better as it essentially has a glass coating on the face.

I agree with Sean.   The grease is not getting behind the tile. the tile is absorbing it.  It was probably never sealed.

Remove the filter and take another picture. It's unlikely that the hood is designed so that it would drip behind the tiles, but that would show clearly how it was designed.

I would agree with Ecnerwal that your first step should be to take it apart and inspect the hood for aging or installation errors. Hoods collect grease and need to be cleaned frequently. I worked as a cook in my youth and the hood at the restaurant had a grease pan where it would collect and was dumped weekly or so. The hood itself we cleaned with pure ammonia to cut the grease every few months. The filter media should be removed and cleaned as needed depending on how often you use the stove.

That sheet metal seam in the corner may not be sealed well, if at all, and letting oil leak behind the cabinet.
